# Help replicating a material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I'm trying to replicate this material in Cycles (the outer shell of the cell)

[image: cell material]

I think it's a principled shader with 0.94 transmission and 1.0 IOR, and a bump map, but when I use this parameters in Cycles this is what I get

[image: nodes]

[image: material result]

My question is, in the example material, the surface has some roughness that is missing in my material, mine is shinier.  Could it be an effect of the lighting setup?  I would like to achieve this "silk" appearance of the reference material without sacrificing transparency.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By instinct, "silky" for me means:

- more roughness
- some subsurface scattering
- added translucency
- to enhance the bump effect, a IOR slightly less than 1 (0.99 works already!)

[image]

[image]

⚠ Blender 2.80 → 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

IMO it might be as simple as a Glossy shader mixed to a Transparent shader:

[image: material example]

I also added a little roughness control, as your reference looks like it has some kind of noise.